# Object spawns thread in a unit test

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I am trying to spawn 2 threads, one to stream some data to a multicast address, and the other is the actual code being tested, it monitors the multicast address and tells me if something is streaming.

The `monitor.StartMonitoring();` and `streamer.SendData();` basically run a private method from their respective class in a long running thread. The behavior of those thread is as described earlier.

I'm seeing weird behavior, if I run the test in debug mode and run the code line by line, I see that nothing happens until I run the `Thread.Sleep(5000)`. When it reaches Thread.Sleep(), I see traffic on the multicast address, and if I inspect the `UdpMonitor` class, I see that it has a up to date status value of the multicast address (it says that it is indeed streaming). As if the other threads were being blocked for running by the test thread. Is this normal?

```
[TestMethod]
public void UdpMonitorTest_Typical()
{
   var monitor = new UdpMonitor(multicastIp, nicIp, monitorNicPort);
   monitor.StartMonitoring();

   var streamer = new UdpDummyStreamer(multicastIp, nicIp, dummyNicPort, multicastPort);
   streamer.SendData();

   Thread.Sleep(5000);

   Assert.AreEqual(BroadcastEndpointStatus.Streaming, monitor.GetEndpointStatus());
}
```

Comment: not sure which test engine you are using, but most of them require a very specific way to test multithreading

Comment: its the default test framework with visual studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically all threads are stopped when you're stepping through code in debug, so yes, this is normal.

I'd recommend making use of a `ManualResetEvent` or similar to ensure that your thread starts and stops as you expect; otherwise, the test runner will think the test is completed while the thread (in the background) is still happily working away. Unit testing multithreaded code is **hard**.